# How to change File Permissions in Liferay 6.2 sync (Liferay Sync Connector plugin)

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I am using **[Liferay Sync Connector](https://web.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/31709100)** plugin in **liferay 6.2**

For accessing document and media folder data on my computer I am using **[Liferay Sync](https://www.liferay.com/supporting-products/liferay-sync)**.

**Liferay Sync Connector plugin** provide permission like,

- View Only
- View and Add Discussion
- View, Update, and Add Discussion
- Full Access (Add Discussion, Delete, Update, View)

By default, this permission applies to the Site Member role.

How can I apply the above permission on custom created role or other then Site Member role ??